# how my app can see, what wifi change to another network

Tags: objective-c, wifi, reachability

i use Reachability library, and need see when mac adress change, and my app connect to another network

if it's my network i start timer and update my UITableView, and after user exit from my wifi network of change wifi network - stop timer and update UITableView

but i see only online/offline wi fi connect

how to see change wifi router ?

```
-(void)setUpSeacrhWiFi{

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(networkChange:) name:kReachabilityChangedNotification object:nil];

Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
[reachability startNotifier];

_status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];
if(_status == ReachableViaWiFi){

    NSLog(@"wi fi online");

    [self searchCLubs];
}else{

    NSLog(@"wi fi failed");

    [_mainOfficeTableView reloadData];
}
```

}

```
(void)networkChange:(NSNotification *) notif{

NSLog(@"wi fi");
Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForLocalWiFi];
_status = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

if (_status == ReachableViaWiFi) {
    NSLog(@"connect wi-fi");

    [self searchCLubs];
}else{

    if ([timer isValid]) {
        [timer invalidate];

        NSString *timeStr = [self returnTimeFromStr:countTimer];

        UIAlertView *alertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"in club " message:timeStr delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:@"Ок" otherButtonTitles: nil];
        [alertView show];

        countTimer = 0;
    }

    _inClub = false;
    [_mainOfficeTableView reloadData];
}
```

}

Comment: Your mac address will not change when you connect to a different address. You can check the outside IP address to see if it is different than before.

Comment: yeah, i need check outside ip, but i need see when change wi fi router